# How to set the default Android RecognitionService?

Tags: android, inheritance, speech

I'm a beginner in Android Development. I'm making a Recognition Speech API with my own speech recognizer algorithm. I discovered that Android offers a class named RecognitionService that provides callbacks that solves my problem.

The question is: If i extend this class and I create my own RecognitionService, how a third programmer can use my class and set his default RecognitionService as the default recognitionservice in the system, or at least in a button or another Android view component.

Thank you for all.

Comment: Make your own library as a Recognition Service  third party library and make available to others by uploading it openly on any platforms.

Comment: Hi GrIsHu, what I need is to know how the third programmer instantiates my own class that extends Android RecognitionService, or the way to implement my class. Is in a button? is in a general property of the system? I don't know how works the Android RecognitionService class and how to set a class that extends of this by the default Speech Recognition Service in the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Kõnele project (http://kaljurand.github.io/K6nele/about/), which implements the `RecognitionService`-interface.

Other apps can directly call this implementation using the 2-argument `createSpeechRecognizer`, e.g.

```
SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this,
    new ComponentName(
        "ee.ioc.phon.android.speak",
        "ee.ioc.phon.android.speak.SpeechRecognitionService");
    );
```

With the 1-argument call the system default is returned. The user can set the default via:

```
Settings -> Language & input -> Speech -> Voice input
```

Comment: Thanks for all Kaarel!